# Facebook on Android: What kind of intent is used by links clicked from wall posts?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

I have a question regarding some implementation details of the Facebook app for Android.

When clicking a web link from within Facebook (e.g. a web article posted in News Feed), I would guess that it creates and sends some kind of Intent object for the http/https link that a capable web browser app can receive and use to open that link.

I'm looking to make an app that can receive that Intent to potentially do something more useful with it, instead of always sending it to a web browser. I need to know a few things so that my app will successfully capture that intent:

- What kind of Intent is it?
- What action and categories are specified?
- Are there any other specific details I might need to know?

I appreciate any help or links to resources that may point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:**

One thing I would like to know specifically is whether this intent is sent to Broadcast Receiver components instead of to activities or services. If so, I can just use Tasker to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are probably looking to do something similar to this tutorial 
http://blog.vogella.com/2011/02/21/android-intents/

Although I can't be certain of what Facebook is calling, I know that all of my current browsers on my Tablet have the option of being used. I would assume they are using

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
```

Keep in mind that if you register your app in this way you will look like a browser to all apps, not just the Facebook app as you suggested.

Comment: Well, I would be filtering the intents as well. Links coming out of the Facebook app always look something like `http://facebook.com/l.php?u=<URL-encoded link>`, so similar to how YouTube matches links with youtube.com, my app will be able to match links coming from the Facebook app.

Comment: Good idea. I forgot that Facebook uses that standard hyperlink convention. One more word of advice if you are thinking of doing that, there is an option under facebook settings to use secure (HTTPS). Make sure that users who have this option enabled will still trigger your app. AKA include links beginning with https rather than http as well

Comment: Good call, thanks. BTW, I'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation lol.